# Android quick action popup inside a list view

Tags: android, android-listview

What is the best way to create a custom popup window like quick action in iOS within a list view?

Answer (score 0):

You can user Dialog or popup Window with setting the exact position .. Or for a better view 
try this [libary](https://github.com/kvirair/Quick-Action)